# Sort Dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary for example like `{"abc": 3, "dcb": 4, "dab": 4, "dfb": 5}`.
I would like to sort it by value and by keys, where the value is more important than the key.
So in our example we would get:

```
{"dfb" : 5, "dab" : 4, "dcb" : 4, "abc" : 3}
```

More preferably if it is presented as a list rather than dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sorted` on the dictionary items with the reversed order as key to make the value the major key, and negative value for descending order:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

Output:

```
[('dfb', 5), ('dab', 4), ('dcb', 4), ('abc', 3)]
```

*NB. the exact expected output is unclear but you can easily convert to dictionary or list of lists from there*

```
dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))
# {'dfb': 5, 'dab': 4, 'dcb': 4, 'abc': 3}
```